# A transformation for independent variables to be dependent

Tags: machine-learning, classification, feature-selection

I ran into a confusing question.

> If two variables are independent, maybe they will be dependent after linear transformation.

How it can happen? Is it possible for independent variables?

What is the operation that it makes variables to be dependent?

> In my opinion the transformation that maps all variables to a point is true for this fact.

What is wrong with my answer?

The mean of Variables are features of data.

Comment: By mapping all variables to a point, do you mean a constant function, e.g. $f(x)=3$

Comment: I was actually asking about your answer, i.e. "In my opinion the transformation that maps all variables to a point is true for this fact." . Does mapping all variables to a point mean applying a constant function to your random variables?

Comment: The first quotation is confusing in that it refers to at least *three* variables: the original two plus any components of the "linear transformation." What, then, does "they will be dependent" refer to? If to the original variables, the answer is obviously no; but if it refers to something else--such as the components of the linear transformation--then certainly the answer could be yes. For instance, let the linear transformation map $(X,Y)$ to $(X,X).$

Comment: My example relies on two facts, both of which are straightforward to demonstrate from the definitions: first, when $X$ is an (almost surely) nonconstant random variable, $(X,X)$ is not independent; second, the transformation $(X,Y)\to(X,X)$ is linear.

Comment: @gunes I mean "mapping all variables to a point mean applying a constant function to your random variables"

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what they mean by linear transformation. If the linear transform is a unary function, then by applying to each independent variable you end up with two new independent variables. If the linear transform is a binary function, i.e., it is a linear combination of both independent variables, then you will have created a new dependent variable.

For both cases your answer isn't correct because two variables that have the same constant value are still independent.

Comment: Would you please clarify a bit more the last sentence?

Comment: If you have two independent random variables, A and B, and you create new random variables using a trivial linear function f(x) = 0 * x + 3, you get C = f(A) = 3 and D = f(B) = 3, where C and D are the new variables. The fact that these variables always take on the same value doesn't make them dependent. C and D are still independent.

Answer (score 0):

No, this cannot happen.

> In my opinion the transformation that maps all variables to a point is true for this fact.

> What is wrong with my answer?

Don't take this the wrong way, but most teachers to courses in this topic would probably first note that your opinion has nothing to do with it.

You should start with the definition of independence. There are multiple ways to do it, but most likely you work with a definition like,

$X$ and $Y$ are independent if for any $a$ and $b$, $P(X < a)\cdot P(Y < b) == P(X < a \text{ and } Y < b)$.

Now let's say you know $X$ and $Y$ are independent, but you want to prove that $c X  + d$ is independent of $eY + f$. Those are the general forms of a linear transformation. Then, given an arbitrary $a$ and $b$, how can you show that the above property also holds for these transformations?

### Edit

Actually, to answer your question more directly instead of starting with a proof, if you map everything on a point $X$ and $Y$ are still independent.

Let's say you map both $X$ and $Y$ to a single point $c$. Then $P(X < a)$ is either zero or one, depending on if $c < a$ or not. The same goes for $P(Y < b)$, and if you plug those numbers into the definition, you'll see that the equation holds true for all $a$ and $b$, and therefore, these transformations of $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

This is a special case of the general situation, where, using the numbers above, $c = 0$ in $cX + d$ and $e = 0$.

Comment: Hey Rayna, as I explained above, that cannot happen. I've given you the start of a proof. The other comment below also explains to you that this does not work. You don't really seem to understand, read or acknowledge the answers here. I'm not really willing to dig deeper for you until you do. Maybe you should ask simpler questions?

Comment: Looked for one but couldn't find it immediately. Why don't you try it based on above, ask a new question if you're stuck. First maybe try to prove that two "constant" variables are independent.